# Angular Apollo use response from refetch query within a mutation

Tags: angular, graphql, apollo

I'm working on an Angular project with Apollo and GraphQL. I have a mutation that updates a list of accounts with relevant details associated with it. After the successful mutation, I am using refetchqueries to query the API for updated list of accounts. Everything works till this part.

```
this.apollo.mutate({
        mutation: mutationCreateNewAccount,
        variables: {
            accountNumber: this.accountNumber,
            accountType: this.accountType,
            routingNumber: this.routingNumber,
            nameOfAcountHolder: this.name
        },
        refetchQueries: [{
            query: queryAccounts,
            variables: { accountNumber: this.accountNumber }
        }]}).subscribe(({ data }) => console.log(data),
```

The 'data' for the subscription returns response from the mutation but is there a way I could use the data returned by 'queryAccounts' which is also run as part of this mutation?

There seems to be a way to do this in react but I was unsuccessful to do something similar in Angular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mentioned there are ways to do it in react and which I don't think is true.

Let me explain how mutations work in Apollo.

1. You run `apollo.mutate()` with `refetchQueries` option
2. When you subscribe to it, the HTTP request is made (in most cases, sometimes WS or some other transportation layer)
3. Apollo receives the response from the server.
4. Updates the store.
5. Observable you subscribed to emits the result (your `console.log(data)`)
6. Next, each query specified in `refetchQueries` starts a new HTTP request and runs against the server.
7. Apollo updates the store on each response.
8. Components that listen to those queries get updated results

I explained it here, in docs: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/angular/features/cache-updates.html#after-mutations

Basically, refetchQueries is not to fetch or access data.

Answer (score 2):

You can have a watchQuery that will always update when refetched

```
this.apollo.watchQuery({
            query: query,
            variables: variables
        })
        .valueChanges
        .pipe(
            map(res => res.data)
        )
        .subscribe(data => {
            //Updated your data here
        }, err => {

        })
       })
```

Comment: Sure. But I thought there would be a way to access the query response without having to create a new watchQuery and subscription.